# xyzzy の modifier キー(Ctrl)をF13などに変更する方法

Tags: windows, xyzzy

WindowsでCapslockキーをCtrlキーにOSレベルで切り替えて使っていたのですが、
Ctrlキーと動作をかぶらないように`F13`をCapslockに割り当てようと思っています。

具体的にはMacのようにEmacs風のテキスト操作を追加したいのですが
Ctrl+Aですべて選択のような動作も残したく考えています。

ただ xyzzy ではCapslockキーをそのままCtrlの代わりとして使いたいので
設定ファイルの先頭に『`F13`をCtrlキーとして使う』という記述をし
残りは既存の設定をそのまま使いたいと思っているのですが可能でしょうか？

可能であればその方法を、もし不可能であれば代替の方法を教えて下さい。

Comment: ここ、参考になりませんかね？http://edutainment-fun.com/script/xyzzy/textEditor/setKey.html

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。`kbd-translate-table`あたりを触ればなんとかなるかと思って試してみたのですが無理そうでした…。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MacのようにEmacs風のカーソル操作方法のキーバインドと既存の`ctrl+a`ですべて選択などの動作を共存させるには`F13`を使う必要はありませんでした。

右CtrlだけにAutohotkeyでEmacs風のカーソル操作を設定し、xyzzyを除外する設定にすれば
左Ctrl側との動作のかぶり無く使えるようになりました。

以下がそのAutohotkey(v2)でのコードになります。

```
#If not WinActive("ahk_exe xyzzy.exe")
  >^a::Home
  >^e::End
  >^f::Right
  >^b::Left
  >^p::Up
  >^n::Down
  >^h::BackSpace
  >^d::Del
  >^y::^v
  >^k::Send "+{END}^x"
  >^l::Send "+{HOME}^x"
#If
```

(あとから見直すと質問内容が不十分だったため、質問を追記した上で回答を投稿しています。)

Answer (score -2):

確かブートメニューで変えれたと思います。
Windowsがきどうするまえにf2などのキーをおして設定ができたと思います